# Output PHP to Textbox

Tags: php, textbox

I'm trying to get the result of a multiplication done in php to show up in a form's textbox. How to do it in php?

Comment: I don't know how to echo into a form's textbox. I wrote

        echo $_POST["1"] * $_POST["2"];

but don't know how to make it apper in a textbox instead of a new page.

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were asking HOW to print out the result on the SAME page without going to the next page.

Here's how it works (off my head)

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$result=$_POST['num1']*$_POST['num2'];
}
?>
<html><body>
<form action="#" method="post">
Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
Num2:<input name="num2">
Answer: <input value="<?php if (isset($result)) echo $result ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<?php

$result = 1 * 764000;

?>

...
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" />
...
```

Comment: I think it will be something like this, but I can't get it together. I'm trying to multiply with a form's data. It looks like this:

        <?php

$result = $_POST["1"] * $_POST["2"];

?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" />

Comment: It looks like you might be asking the wrong question, then. It doesn't appear that your problem is how to output it anymore, but rather how to multiply variables from the form. You may want to ask that question separately. Be sure to include detail about what output you're getting and what output you expect.

Comment: I've done that and it works, but it opens the result in a separate window. I'd like it to write it inside the form I've asked the numbers in.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're looking for here, so this is a bit of a wild guess.

```
<textarea id="value" name="value"><?php echo $contents; ?></textarea>
```

That will echo your PHP variable ($contents) in your textarea.

EDIT: Sorry if you meant an input of type text. I was thinking textarea because you called it a "textbox".